# qt qrc can't load image

Tags: c++, qt

I have a qrc file where i added a image (i.png)

The qrc file looks like this

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>i.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And this is how I try to use the file

```
QPixmap pixmap(":/images/i.png");
```

After some searching around i saw someone said I should chance it to:

```
QPixmap pixmap(":/i.png");
```

But this doesnt work ether

Any ideas to why this isn't working?

Comment: Can you show your code that reproduces the issue along with the project file? This should work and I cannot personally reproduce it. There could be many issues causing this.

Comment: You should edit your question to precise how it works using qmake. And then ask the question you want an answer for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `QPixmap pixmap(":/images/i.png");` is the right one. If it does not work, it is probably because the compiled resource file is either not linked with the binary, or not initialized.

If your resource is loaded from a library, [you need to call](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html#using-resources-in-a-library):

```
Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resources);
```

Comment: I think it is better to ask for clarification in comments than submitting guessing answers. Your answers may not help the OP if your assumption is not OK.

Comment: I guess that running qmake, link it with the binary? because that fixed my problem?

Comment: @Sumsar1812 As said Laszlo, you should show the relevant parts of (or all of) your project file, so that one can understand better why that fails. Do you link the resource file with a shared library?

Comment: @lrineau no no, you don't understand. Running qmake made it work. My question is now was it because it wasn't linked to the binary or something else ?